# Get which position a child has in its parent in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Given I have:

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
  <Child /> <!-- this is Child 2 -->
  <Child />
  <Child /> <!-- this is Child 4 -->
</Parent>
```

how do I know within the `Child` component which position it has in its parent. I obviously could pass it down like this:

`<Child :position="2" />` but that creates unnecessary markup when there is a computed way to do this.

I want to access within `Child` its `-nth` position in the parent.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: @Khauri I have a condition which checks on which position the child is and depending on that does something with a corresponding function in an array. Again I could easily solve this by passing a prop, I just thought it would not be necessary.

Comment: Where is that condition? In Parent? Child? Would using v-for on the array and directly passing the function as a prop to the child not work for you? (The markup would actually be very simple).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why do you need this information: if you need some specific styles for `nth` component, it's better to use `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` CSS selectors.
Passing the position number within a prop is also a nice way to do it.

You also may refer to `$parent` and iterate over its children to find the current element, like `[...this.$parent.$el.children].findIndex(child => child === this.$el)` (make sure both parent and child have already been mounted), but this code is quite fragile so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Yeah I don't need it for styling at all.

Comment: Try to refer to `$parent` then.